# Applications of linear fractional relationship

Tags: economics, oc.optimization-and-control

This may be the wrong forum, but are there any natural contexts (physics, economics, etc.) in which one might observe the relationship $y = ax/(bx+c)$ between a pair of variables $x$ and $y$?  General linear fractional expressions come up all the time in optimization but I've had a hard time finding a really simple and natural context where this might arise.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Michaelis-Menten equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michaelis%E2%80%93Menten_kinetics) in biochemistry.